# Passing session variable through AJAX to PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session-variables

My goal is to pass `$userId` variable (which contains the session variable), through an ajax statement, into a php file that contains an echoed form. The purpose is so that when the form is submitted the session variable can be inserted into the database and then used as a way to identify which entries where done by which users.

Im having a bit of trouble getting the variable data to go to the ajax statement. What am i doing wrong?

```
<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {

    $userId = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['userid']);

    echo $userId;

    echo ' (irrelevant code)...

        //button that loads form via ajax...
        <a href="#" class="small button radius expand" onClick="showAdd(\'$userId\');return false;">Add URL</a>

    (irrelevant code)... ';
}
```

AJAX code:

```
function showAdd(str)   {
     $('#response').html('Processing Request. Please wait a moment...');
       var userId = str;
       alert (userId);

       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "addUrlForm.php",   
           data: "userId=" + str,                                        
           success: function(msg)   {
               $('#response').empty();
               $('#content01').html(msg).show();
           },
           error: function () {
               alert('error');
        }   
    });
};
```

EDIT: I took your suggestion (thank-you) and it some-what helped. Now the alert is returning "$userId" variable as a string. How do I make it be recognised as a variable containing the session data, not as a string? I tried "showAdd($userId)" but console is telling me $userId is not defined?.

Comment: Since you are sending the userId as a parameter to your `showAdd()` function shouldn't the code be `var userId = str;` or simply change the name of the parameter to `userId` and you should be good to go.

Comment: If it helped you perhaps you should vote up the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're sending the `userId` as a parameter to the `showAdd()` function you should change your code to:

```
function showAdd(str) {
   var userId = str;
   // ...
}
```

or simply rename the parameter to `userId`:

```
function showAdd(userId) {
    // use userId here
]
```

To make you above code send the correct `userId` and not the string `$userId` to the function you should wrap your output string in double quotes or output it directly:

```
echo '<a href="#" class="small button radius expand" onClick="showAdd('.$userId.');return false;">Add URL</a>';
```

or:

```
echo "<a href='#' class='small button radius expand' onClick='showAdd($userId);return false;'>Add URL</a>";
```

Comment: Thanks Krister, I had just tried (".$userId."), with the double quotes, got a syntax error and though it was completely wrong haha.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why would you use `$(this)` when the `userid` is already present and is passed as function parameter.

Change this:

```
var userId = $(this).attr('userId');
```

To:

```
var userId = str;
```